# Slow replacement rule while combining symbolic summands

Tags: performance-tuning, replacement, symbolic

**Edit:**

I attempted to use the method of repeatedly using `Replace` instead of `ReplaceRepeated` as suggested by Mr.Wizard, but the issues still remains. The simplest example I could think of is this:

```
PlusRule = { Plus[x_NumSymb,y_NumSymb,b___] :> Plus[NumSymb[Unique[]],b] };

(* just a sum of 16 NumSymb objects *)
testSum = Sum[NumSymb[Unique[]],{i,1,16}];

Table[Timing[Replace[testSum[[Range@n]],PlusRule,{0,Infinity}]][[1]],{n,1,16}]

(*
{0.000059, 0.000079, 0.000055, 0.000087, 0.000191, 0.000534, \
0.001428, 0.001097, 0.003493, 0.010644, 0.033112, 0.102373, 0.314284, \
0.980085, 3.05019, 9.41216}
*)

Table[Timing[ReplaceAll[testSum[[Range@n]],PlusRule]][[1]],{n,1,16}]

(*
{0.000043, 0.000059, 0.000047, 0.000073, 0.000183, 0.000548, \
0.001664, 0.001987, 0.003545, 0.010998, 0.034157, 0.102945, 0.326322, \
1.0214, 3.12903, 9.52135}
*)

Table[Timing[ReplaceRepeated[testSum[[Range@n]],PlusRule]][[1]],{n,1,16}]

(*
{0.000063, 0.000063, 0.00006, 0.000109, 0.000265, 0.000785, 0.002295, \
0.002188, 0.005639, 0.015812, 0.048789, 0.151387, 0.487731, 1.5194, \
4.65665, 14.1617}
*)
```

The timings get much worse with more terms. I still do not see what is so bad about the replacement, especially with an expression so simple.

**End Edit**

I have a rational expression with very large numerical coefficients, which I want to replace with placeholder symbols to improve the runtime in later operations.

My idea was to replace each coefficient with some unique object `NumSymb[$1234]` via

```
expr //.{Times[a_/;And[!MatchQ[a,_NumSymb],AllTrue[{Mu1,MuTilde1},FreeQ[a,#]&]],b___]:>Times[NumSymb[Unique[]],b],
         Plus[a_/;And[!MatchQ[a,_NumSymb],AllTrue[{Mu1,MuTilde1},FreeQ[a,#]&]],b___]:>Plus[NumSymb[Unique[]],b]}
```

where  `{Mu1,MuTilde1}` are the free variables in `expr`. In my special case this leads to

```
NumSymb[$22929]*(NumSymb[$22930]*(NumSymb[$22936] + NumSymb[$22938]*(NumSymb[$22966]*(NumSymb[$23010] + Mu1*MuTilde1*NumSymb[$23041] + NumSymb[$23064]/(Mu1*MuTilde1)) + 
      (NumSymb[$22983]*(NumSymb[$22992] + Mu1^2*MuTilde1^2*NumSymb[$23002]))/(NumSymb[$23030] + Mu1*MuTilde1*NumSymb[$23066] + NumSymb[$23084]/(Mu1*MuTilde1))) + 
    NumSymb[$22939]*(NumSymb[$22956] + NumSymb[$22962]*(NumSymb[$23003]*(NumSymb[$23057] + Mu1*MuTilde1*NumSymb[$23086] + NumSymb[$23100]/(Mu1*MuTilde1)) + 
        (NumSymb[$23022]*(NumSymb[$23033] + Mu1^2*MuTilde1^2*NumSymb[$23046]))/(NumSymb[$23079] + Mu1*MuTilde1*NumSymb[$23102] + NumSymb[$23108]/(Mu1*MuTilde1))))) + 
  NumSymb[$22931]*(NumSymb[$22937] + NumSymb[$22940]*(NumSymb[$22970]*(NumSymb[$23014] + Mu1*MuTilde1*NumSymb[$23048] + NumSymb[$23070]/(Mu1*MuTilde1)) + 
      (NumSymb[$22987]*(NumSymb[$22997] + Mu1^2*MuTilde1^2*NumSymb[$23007]))/(NumSymb[$23036] + Mu1*MuTilde1*NumSymb[$23072] + NumSymb[$23089]/(Mu1*MuTilde1))) + 
    NumSymb[$22941]*(NumSymb[$22959] + NumSymb[$22965]*(NumSymb[$23008]*(NumSymb[$23062] + Mu1*MuTilde1*NumSymb[$23091] + NumSymb[$23103]/(Mu1*MuTilde1)) + 
        (NumSymb[$23027]*(NumSymb[$23039] + Mu1^2*MuTilde1^2*NumSymb[$23053]))/(NumSymb[$23083] + Mu1*MuTilde1*NumSymb[$23105] + NumSymb[$23109]/(Mu1*MuTilde1))))))
```

To further reduce size I am trying to expand this expression, and combine sums or products into single `NumSymb` objects. For products this works well, and is very fast:

```
Timing[Expand[%]//.{
        Times[a1_NumSymb,a2_NumSymb,b__] :> Times[NumSymb[Unique[]],b],
        Times[a1_NumSymb,a2_NumSymb] :> NumSymb[Unique[]]
    }]
(*
{0.000608, NumSymb[$23991] + NumSymb[$23992] + NumSymb[$24015] + NumSymb[$24016] + NumSymb[$24037] + NumSymb[$24038] + Mu1*MuTilde1*NumSymb[$24039] + 
  Mu1*MuTilde1*NumSymb[$24040] + NumSymb[$24043]/(Mu1*MuTilde1) + NumSymb[$24044]/(Mu1*MuTilde1) + 
  NumSymb[$24045]/(NumSymb[$23887] + Mu1*MuTilde1*NumSymb[$23923] + NumSymb[$23941]/(Mu1*MuTilde1)) + 
  (Mu1^2*MuTilde1^2*NumSymb[$24046])/(NumSymb[$23887] + Mu1*MuTilde1*NumSymb[$23923] + NumSymb[$23941]/(Mu1*MuTilde1)) + 
  NumSymb[$24048]/(NumSymb[$23893] + Mu1*MuTilde1*NumSymb[$23929] + NumSymb[$23946]/(Mu1*MuTilde1)) + 
  (Mu1^2*MuTilde1^2*NumSymb[$24049])/(NumSymb[$23893] + Mu1*MuTilde1*NumSymb[$23929] + NumSymb[$23946]/(Mu1*MuTilde1)) + NumSymb[$24057] + NumSymb[$24058] + 
  Mu1*MuTilde1*NumSymb[$24059] + Mu1*MuTilde1*NumSymb[$24060] + NumSymb[$24061]/(Mu1*MuTilde1) + NumSymb[$24062]/(Mu1*MuTilde1) + 
  NumSymb[$24063]/(NumSymb[$23936] + Mu1*MuTilde1*NumSymb[$23959] + NumSymb[$23965]/(Mu1*MuTilde1)) + 
  (Mu1^2*MuTilde1^2*NumSymb[$24064])/(NumSymb[$23936] + Mu1*MuTilde1*NumSymb[$23959] + NumSymb[$23965]/(Mu1*MuTilde1)) + 
  NumSymb[$24065]/(NumSymb[$23940] + Mu1*MuTilde1*NumSymb[$23962] + NumSymb[$23966]/(Mu1*MuTilde1)) + 
  (Mu1^2*MuTilde1^2*NumSymb[$24066])/(NumSymb[$23940] + Mu1*MuTilde1*NumSymb[$23962] + NumSymb[$23966]/(Mu1*MuTilde1))}
*)
```

However, attempting to coalesce the sums of `NumSymb`s in a similar manner is very slow. Just trying this on the first 21 terms takes almost 40 seconds:

```
Timing[%[[2]][[Range@21]]//.{
        Plus[a1_NumSymb,a2_NumSymb,b__] :> Plus[NumSymb[Unique[]], b],
        Plus[a1_NumSymb,a2_NumSymb] :> NumSymb[Unique[]]
    }]
(*
{38.768701, Mu1*MuTilde1*NumSymb[$25170] + Mu1*MuTilde1*NumSymb[$25171] + NumSymb[$25174]/(Mu1*MuTilde1) + NumSymb[$25175]/(Mu1*MuTilde1) + 
  NumSymb[$25176]/(NumSymb[$25018] + Mu1*MuTilde1*NumSymb[$25054] + NumSymb[$25072]/(Mu1*MuTilde1)) + 
  (Mu1^2*MuTilde1^2*NumSymb[$25177])/(NumSymb[$25018] + Mu1*MuTilde1*NumSymb[$25054] + NumSymb[$25072]/(Mu1*MuTilde1)) + 
  NumSymb[$25179]/(NumSymb[$25024] + Mu1*MuTilde1*NumSymb[$25060] + NumSymb[$25077]/(Mu1*MuTilde1)) + 
  (Mu1^2*MuTilde1^2*NumSymb[$25180])/(NumSymb[$25024] + Mu1*MuTilde1*NumSymb[$25060] + NumSymb[$25077]/(Mu1*MuTilde1)) + Mu1*MuTilde1*NumSymb[$25190] + 
  Mu1*MuTilde1*NumSymb[$25191] + NumSymb[$25192]/(Mu1*MuTilde1) + NumSymb[$25193]/(Mu1*MuTilde1) + 
  NumSymb[$25194]/(NumSymb[$25067] + Mu1*MuTilde1*NumSymb[$25090] + NumSymb[$25096]/(Mu1*MuTilde1)) + NumSymb[$25204]}
*)
```

What is the problem with this last replacement rule? I would have naively expected similar speeds as in the product case.

Comment: Your use of `Unique` makes it a little difficult for me to tell if the output is the same, but I suspect you will get better performance by using `Replace`, multiple times if necessary, versus `ReplaceRepeated` for reasons explained in [(20181)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/20181/121).  I also recommend reading [(56062)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/56062/121).

Comment: Thank you, that basically solved the problem. I did not even know that ```Replace``` and ```ReplaceRepeated``` where traversing expressions differently, so I definitely learned something new today. Though it does still seem weird that ```ReplaceRepeated``` was not able to handle the expression above, since it is neither very larger nor very nested.

Comment: Sorry, I was experimenting on an expression which just happened to work out. Once the number becomes large enough, ```Replace``` also grinds to a halt. I added a simple example in my question.

Comment: Your updated example is much better.  Sorry that I didn't spot the right problem before, but hopefully the `Replace` thing and traversal knowledge comes in handy later.  The actual problem arises from the `Flat` and `Orderless` attributes of `Plus`.  I am going to try to find another question I recall that relates to this that should help to explain things.

Comment: I couldn't find exactly what I thought I remembered, but here are some that are at least related: [(105675)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/105675/121), [(130984)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/130984/121), [(206560)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/206560/121).

Comment: Thank you, I think I have a working version now. Particularly the comment in [(130984)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/130984/121) about matching against ```NumSymb[_]``` rather than ```_NumSymb``` was very helpful, as that does seem to improve the efficiency dramatically.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the rule:

```
HoldPattern @ Plus[__NumSymb] :> NumSymb[Unique[]]
```

instead. For example:

```
Table[
    testSum[[Range@n]] /. HoldPattern @ Plus[__NumSymb] :> NumSymb[Unique[]],
    {n, 16}
] //AbsoluteTiming
```

> ```
> {0.000197, {NumSymb[$11], NumSymb[$275], NumSymb[$276], NumSymb[$277],
> NumSymb[$278], NumSymb[$279], NumSymb[$280], NumSymb[$281], NumSymb[$282], 
> NumSymb[$283], NumSymb[$284], NumSymb[$285], NumSymb[$287], NumSymb[$288],
> NumSymb[$289], NumSymb[$290]}}
> ```

**Update**

For your example in the comments:

What's happening is that [`Plus`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Plus) is both [`Flat`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Flat) and [`Orderless`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Orderless), which means that applying patterns can be slow, since all groupings and sorts need to be tried. If you have many symbols, it is better to suppress this behavior somehow. One idea is to use [`Verbatim`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Verbatim) to hide the attributes of [`Plus`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Plus) from the pattern matcher:

```
testSum = Sum[a[i], {i,1,30}] + Sum[NumSymb[Unique[]], {i,1,30}];

testSum /. Verbatim[Plus][a___, Longest[b__NumSymb], c___] :> a + c + NumSymb[Unique[]]
```

> a[1] + a[2] + a[3] + a[4] + a[5] + a[6] + a[7] + a[8] + a[9] + a[10] + a[11] +
> a[12] + a[13] + a[14] + a[15] + a[16] + a[17] + a[18] + a[19] + a[20] +
> a[21] + a[22] + a[23] + a[24] + a[25] + a[26] + a[27] + a[28] + a[29] +
> a[30] + NumSymb[\$551]

Another idea is to create a new wrapper:

```
plus[a___, _NumSymb, b___] := DeleteCases[a+b,_NumSymb] + NumSymb[Unique[]]
plus[a___] := Plus[a]

testSum /. Plus -> plus
```

> a[1] + a[2] + a[3] + a[4] + a[5] + a[6] + a[7] + a[8] + a[9] + a[10] + a[11] +
> a[12] + a[13] + a[14] + a[15] + a[16] + a[17] + a[18] + a[19] + a[20] +
> a[21] + a[22] + a[23] + a[24] + a[25] + a[26] + a[27] + a[28] + a[29] +
> a[30] + NumSymb[\$552]

Comment: This does solve the problem in the case of the example I gave, but I am not sure how to extend it to the case where there are also summands other than ```NumSymb```. For example, applying it to the sum ```testSum = Sum[a[i],{i,1,30}]+Sum[NumSymb[Unique[]],{i,1,30}]``` still is extremely slow, and timings now increase with the number of non ```NumSymb``` terms.

Answer (score 0):

The question [(130984)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/130984/121) pointed out to me by Mr.Wizard in the comments was really helpful. The answer there mentions that matching against an explicit Head like `f[_]` can enable optimizations in the pattern matcher that would not apply when for example using `_f`.

This essentially solved the problem for me, as performing replacements with the pattern

```
HoldPattern@Plus[x:NumSymb[_],y:NumSymb[_]] :> NumSymb[Unique[]]
```

takes only milliseconds even on large expressions.

I still think Carl's solution is much better, since it can be used when not matching against an explicit Head. Also it does not rely on any special behaviour of the pattern matcher, which could change in the future.